# wifi authentication is asked again and again in linux

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

I am using Manjaro Linux xfce on my laptop. It is connected to my home wifi. After some time of connection it shows a dialog box of authentication required.sometimes its connected after i click connect but sometime it doesn't connect and keeps asking for authentication again and again. I have to disconnect the network and reconnect it however it doesn't assure the fix . What is the reason behind this issue and how can i fix it

Comment: 1) How many Wi-Fi routers/repeaters/access points/hotspots do you have? 2) Are you sure that your neighbours didn't pick the same name for their Wi-Fi as yours? Use `nmcli dev wifi list` to check. 3) Run `journalctl -b -u NetworkManager -u wpa_supplicant`, then check whether all MAC addresses/BSSIDs match the ones on your Wi-Fi routers/etc.

Comment: @user1686 i use my main router and my neighbours dont have the same name as mine also my network is hidden.when i ran the command nmcli dev.. it shows two bssid of my wifi.one with the ssid and one without ssid